# Single column data to multiple columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have data of positive or negative floating point values in a single column which is separated by two empty lines.

```
1.0
-2.0


3.0
4.0


-5.0
6.0


-7.0
8.0
```

In bash, what would be the best way to get this data into multiple columns so that the end result looks something like this:

```
1.0 3.0 -5.0 -7.0
-2.0 4.0 6.0 8.0
```

In an ideal situation, the solution would work not only for numbers, but also text separated in a similar way.

Comment: I've was thinking about splitting the data into several arrays and then merging them together, but my attempts to read the file into a variable and then split with something like `(${FILE//\n\n/})` have not been particularly successful.

Comment: That's what I do below, tell me if it is good for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
$ grep -v '^\s*$' file | pr -ts" " --columns 4 
1.0 3.0 -5.0 -7.0
-2.0 4.0 6.0 8.0
```

`grep` is used to remove the blank lines and `pr` to format the output.

Comment: +1 for `pr`, but would be great to see a genericised version.

Comment: `-s" "` might be preferable to `-w20`. Nevertheless, +1

Comment: pipe to `column` for formatting - `grep -v '^\s*$' file | pr -ts" " --columns 4 |  column -t`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/./!d;$!N;2{h;d};G;s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3 \1\n\4 \2/;$!{h;d}' file
```

- `/./!d` if the line does not contain a character delete it.
- `$!N` if the line is not the last append a newline and the following line to the pattern space (PS).
- `2{h;d}` for the second line, copy the PS to the hold space(HS) and then delete it.
- `G` for all other lines append the HS to the PS.
- `s/^(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\3 \1\n\4 \2/` re-arrange the PS into the order that is required.
- `$!{h;d}`for all line except the last copy the PS to the HS and then delete the PS.
  This  means that on encountering the last the line the contents of the PS will be printed out.

Comment: I am first time seeing these wired characters (options) in sed. could you explain what those are and what they doing..

Answer (score 1):

This is a longer but more readable solution:

```
a=() b=() i=0
while read line ; do
    case $i in
        0) a+=($line) ;;
        1) b+=($line) ;;
    esac
    ((i++))
    if ((i == 4)); then i=0; fi
done < data.txt

echo ${a[*]}
echo ${b[*]}
```

Comment: Note you can append to an array like this: `a+=("$line")`

Comment: You could also replace `if ((i == 4)); then i=0; fi` with `((i %= 4))`. And combine with the previous line: `((i = ++i % 4))`

Comment: the a+=($line) syntax wasn't working in my version of bash (in an older version of Puppy Linux), so I used a[${#a[@]}]=$line

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is in file data.txt; you may try this:

```
a=($(< data.txt))
b(){ for((i=$1; i<${#a[*]}; i+=2)); do echo -n "${a[$i]} "; done; echo ;}
b 0
b 1
```

This is certainly not the best way but it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try "massaging" the input with `xargs first`

```
while read a b
do 
  A+=($a) B+=($b)
done < <( xargs -n2 < file )

printf "%s\n" "${A[*]}" "${B[*]}"
```

--

Or

```
while read a; read b; do
  read; read;
  A+=($a) B+=($b)
done < file

printf "%s\n" "${A[*]}" "${B[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

using a single call to awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n\n"}{A=A " " $1;B=B " " $2}END{printf A "\n" B "\n"}' NewFile
```

using posix shell only (with builtins)

```
#!/bin/sh
L=""
R=""
while read A && read B && read dummy && read dumtwo || [ "$A" ];do
    L="$L $A"
    R="$R $B"
done < NewFile
echo $L
echo $R
```

Note: rather than storing the variables in strings $L and $R, you could use bash arrays instead using L_ARRAY+=("$A") or like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
L=()
R=()
while read A && read B && read dummy && read dumtwo || [ "$A" ];do
    L[${#L[@]}]=${A}
    R[${#R[@]}]=${B}
done < NewFile
echo -e "${L[@]}\n${R[@]}"
```

or using sed (2 calls)

```
L=`sed -n 1~4p NewFile`
R=`sed -n 2~4p NewFile`
echo $L
echo $R
```